# In XBL, what is the difference between xbl:attr and xbl:text?

Tags: orbeon, xbl

I am using Orbeon Forms, and here is some sample code from xbl-simple.xhtml

XHTML with XBL Component

```
<foo:test id="my-test-1" myref="value1" foobar="en fr"/>
```

I am trying to understand the difference between (`xbl:text=foobar` vs `value=foobar`)

```
<xxforms:variable name="foobar" xbl:attr="xbl:text=foobar"/>
```

vs

```
<xxforms:variable name="foobar" xbl:attr="value=foobar"/>
```

If they are same then where exactly is `xbl:text` useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are a bit different:

```
<xxforms:variable name="foobar" xbl:attr="xbl:text=foobar"/>
```

translates to:

```
<xxforms:variable name="foobar">en fr</xxforms:variable>
```

And:

```
<xxforms:variable name="foobar" xbl:attr="value=foobar"/>
```

translates to:

```
<xxforms:variable name="foobar" value="en fr"/>
```

In the first case, the value of the variable is the constant string "en fr".

In the second case, it is probably an invalid XPath expression!